# Excel CEILING function equivalent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression

In Ms Excel the CEILING function allows you to round up in steps as below. I need to round up in quarters in a QGIS expression and I would like to avoid something messy involving dividing my number by 4 and multiplying back which is the only way I can think of at present.
[image: Excel CEILING]

The QGIS CEIL function only round to whole numbers

[image: CEIL]

Comment: Fortunately doing multiply/divide is not an extremely hard route. It seems that for example PostgeSQL users must do the same https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-math.html.

Comment: Agreed, something like ceil((number * 0.4))/0.4 works fine but seems a little rough. I guess a custom function would tidy it up if I get to grips with python a bit more

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out in the comment, this formula works well:

`ceil(value/0.25) * 0.25`

[image]

You can try creating a custom function using the function editor:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#function-editor

Comment: yes, you misunderstood the question.  I need to round up in non-decimal steps in this case steps of 0.25  - using round you can round in multiples of 10  and it rounds up and down which is not the same as always rounding up like CEIL and CIELING

Comment: @Sethinacan Now I get it, the answer has been edited.